# Цвет текста не меняется с помощью JS кода

Tags: javascript

```js
let listBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".block__text");

for (element of listBtn) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    listBtn.classList.toggle("change");
  });
}

console.log("success");
```

```css
.block__text.change {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="block__text">Раз</p>
  <p class="block__text">Два</p>
  <p class="block__text">Три</p>
  <p class="block__text">Четыре</p>
</div>
```

Я писал код с той идеей, чтобы он при клике на текст менял его цвет на розовый, но код не выполняется, а выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Как я понял, код не может прочитать свойства значения undefined? Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка, я не понимаю

Comment: `listBtn.classList.toggle("change");` => `this.classList.toggle("change");` манипуляции с классом проводить надо у текущего эл-та, а вы делали это для списка нод (listBtn - список всех выбранных эл-тов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте в обработчике события ссылку на сам элемент события с помощью *this* :

```js
let listBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.block__text');

for (element of listBtn) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('change');
  });
}
```

```css
.block__text.change {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="block__text">Раз</p>
  <p class="block__text">Два</p>
  <p class="block__text">Три</p>
  <p class="block__text">Четыре</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blockTextNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".block__text");

for (const blockTextNode of blockTextNodes) {
  blockTextNode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    blockTextNode.classList.toggle("block__text_change");
  });
}
```

```css
.block__text_change {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="block__text">Раз</p>
  <p class="block__text">Два</p>
  <p class="block__text">Три</p>
  <p class="block__text">Четыре</p>
</div>
```